# How to use PythonInterpreter in Java project Intellij - Jython

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jython

I try to using PythonInterpreter in Java but I can't import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter package in Intellij. So the code below can't compile :

```
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter; 
import org.python.core.*; 

public class SimpleEmbedded { 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws PyException { 
        PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();

        System.out.println("Hello, brave new world");
        interp.exec("import sys");
        interp.exec("print sys");

        interp.set("a", new PyInteger(42));
        interp.exec("print a");
        interp.exec("x = 2+2");
        PyObject x = interp.get("x");

        System.out.println("x: "+x);
        System.out.println("Goodbye, cruel world");
    }
}
```

I tried to download jython zip library but Intellij not recognize this library. Any suggest for me?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have installed **Jython** correctly into the project.

- The jar file should be downloaded from the [page](https://www.jython.org/download.html). In your case I recommend to use `Jython Standalone` option.
- Add the jar file as a library according to the official JetBrains [guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html).

If everything is fine with the project configuration but the problem remains you can try to perform the following actions:

- `File | Invalidate Caches / Restart...`
- Close the IDE.
- Remove all `.idea` files from the project.
- Remove/Rename IntelliJ IDEA cache files according to the following [guide](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs).
- Import the project from existing sources. `(File | New | Project from Existing Sources...)`